# Regex Match and Replace path to file

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am trying to do a regex match and replace for hotfile.com links to mp3 files i have in my database (Wordpress).

I used to use hotfile for streaming mp3 files on my site, now i switched to a CDN, could someone kindly help me out with this:

Replace: http//hotfile.com/dl/157490069/c8732d4/mp3_file_name.mp3
With: http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/mp3_file_name.mp3

I have been trying a simple Search and Replace like this: http//hotfile.com/dl/%/%/, but its not working.

It would have been easier to perform a search and replace if hotfile.com didn't have different folders for all files, below is 2 examples of the problem:

http//hotfile.com/dl/155490069/c7932d4/
http//hotfile.com/dl/165490070/c8745e7/

I have over 500 files to replace.

Thanks

Comment: What tool will you use to perform regex replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you must be using mysql for your wordpress database, you can do this replacement either by regex as you asked:

Regex pattern :  `#http://(www.)?hotfile.com/\w+/\w+/\w+/#`

Replacement pattern: `http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/`

An alternate simpler solution would be to extract the mp3 file name using simple string functions of mysql e.g.

1. Use [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) or [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract file name of your mp3 file i.e. find the string after last occurence of "/" in your hotfiles url.
2. Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to append the file name retreived to new url prefix and update it in the database.

Here is an example, you can appropriately change it for your database:

```
mysql> select * from test_songs;
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| song_url                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://hotfile.com/dl/157490069/c8732d4/mp3_file_name.mp3     |
| http://www.hotfile.com/dl/123412312/dd732d4/mp3_song_name.mp3 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Taking substrings:

```
mysql> select SUBSTRING_INDEX(song_url,"/",-1) from test_songs;
+----------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(song_url,"/",-1) |
+----------------------------------+
| mp3_file_name.mp3                |
| mp3_song_name.mp3                |
+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Creating final update query:

```
mysql> Update test_songs set song_url =
CONCAT("http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/",
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(song_url,"/",-1)) ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
```

Checking the results :

```
mysql> select * from test_songs;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| song_url                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/mp3_file_name.mp3 |
| http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/mp3_song_name.mp3 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Done !

Comment: Thanks for your input Dhruv, well i am basically using a wordpress plugin to do that (Search Regex), so i dont do it direct through the database, here is a little more of how the plugin works: http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/wordpress/mass-edit-wordpress-posts-with-regular-expressions-3396/. All im looking for is a Regex that will replace http//hotfile.com/dl/165490070/c8745e7/ with my new cdndomain.com.. any help?

Comment: @user1635292 edited my answer to include regex version first.

Comment: I appreciate that Dhruv, unfortunately still no luck, its not finding the url's when i do the search, could it be this (www.)? since all the hotfile url's i have has no www. it all starts http://hotfile.com ... any clue?

Comment: @user1635292 `(www.)?` will ignore if www is not present. I see the examples u provided do have `http//` in them instead of `http://`, could that be a reason.

Comment: Never mind Dhruv, it works like magic.. I was missing a caracter. How i wish i could buy a beer for you. Thanks man, you made my day :)

Comment: Definitely. Done! Have an awesome day, Dhruv.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as http://regex101.com/r/lK9wH4 should work:
`/^.+\/(.+)$/` and replace with `<your_new_url>\1`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Lindrian, im just a little confused on how to proceed as i am new with Regex. Could you kindly get a little more into details with me?

Comment: Im basically getting: Invalid regular expression: No ending delimiter '^' found .. any help?

Comment: The delimiter is `/`, don't ommit that part.

Answer (score 0):

you can use notepad++ to search and replace all your files

for this particular sample:

search and replace in regex mode:

search "http//hotfile.com/(.*)/(.*.mp3) "

replace "http//p.music.cdndomain.com/vod/music.folder/2010/\2 "

remove the quote mark but keep the space at the end

updated: screencapture for notepad++

[image]

Comment: Thanks kite, just tried and got this error: Invalid regular expression: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash .. any clue to why that?

Comment: updated with screenshot for the notepad++. cannot help with your delimiter error message, never found error like that with notepad++